# Searching in a Range with a Range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a list of vendors in range "A1:A250", and I have a report with vendors that haven't paid last month's bill in other worksheets.

I want to search throughout A1:A250 with another column, let's say "B1:B45", and highlight the names of those vendors that haven't paid.

Here is some sample data:

[image: @BI can't really share with you the data because I'm working on a work-related file, but it's something like this:]

Comment: I'm not sure why you need VBA to do this, sounds like a formula could work. Can you provide some sample data and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Which formula do you have in mind? I tried with the VBA to highlight a certain cell when the .value is matched with my data, but to be honest, it does work only when my data is 1 cell big.... and I have to match like a 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) with a `MATCH` formula will do that. No need for VBA here.

Select column A and add conditional formatting with formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0),0)<>0
```

[image]

When ever you add or remove names in column B the highlighting changes immediatelty.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much!